# How can I manage a project`s asemblies in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, crud, assemblies

How can I manage a project`s asemblies in .NET Core?

I created a WebAPI project with the help of the `dotnet new webapi` command in the VS Code.

Now I would like to know how I can manage assemblies in the project. That means that I would like to be able to check to which assembly each type in the project belongs. I would like to change the assembly to which each type belongs. And I would like to be able to create a new assembly and add project types into it. How can I do all of this?

I believe that there is a single point from which the project assemblies management is possible. But I was not able to find it.

**UPDATE**

After the comments I decided to provide one of the cases where it is necessary to manage assemblies.

I am learning the AutoMapper. And in [this](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html) tutorial there is the following example:

```
// Scan for all profiles in an assembly
// ... using instance approach:
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddMaps(myAssembly);
});
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddMaps(myAssembly));

// Can also use assembly names:
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.AddMaps(new [] {
        "Foo.UI",
        "Foo.Core"
    });
);

// Or marker types for assemblies:
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.AddMaps(new [] {
        typeof(HomeController),
        typeof(Entity)
    });
);
```

In this example it is supposed that I can easily check the name of the assembly to which a type belongs. And also from this example I can tell that it is possible to use different assemblies for different types in the same project (because the `HomeController` and the `Entity` classes are in the same project, but in the different assemblies).

**NB**

I am very confused by the behavior of people on SO. Why did I get two close votes for not providing details to my question if the details were not previously requested in the comments section? IMHO that is very rude and have no reason behind it.

Comment: *I would like to be able to check to which assembly each file in the project belongs*: **each file in a project** is the **assembly**. Therefore I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: One compiled project == one assembly from that project. Everything else is either framework stuff or referenced projects or assemblies from nuget packages.

Comment: What is your question exactly this feels like xyz problem, or you are making some conclusions based on some other language outside .NET world?

Comment: There are strangely contradicting comments. The comment from the `Christian Gollhardt` states that each file is a separate assembly, while the comment from the `Optional Option` states that the whole project is just a single assembly. Does that mean that it is possible to configure and manage assemblies in a project manually as one wish?

Comment: @kuskmen, does it feel to you like an xyz problem after I added the **UPDATE** section? Thank you.

Comment: @qqqqqqq no, I mean all files in one project are compiled into a single assembly.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt, but you wrote the opposite: `each file in a project is the assembly`

Comment: Are you assuming namespace == assembly? They are completely orthogonal concepts. One project creates one and only one assembly. Bit each assembly can contain multiple namespaces, and each namespace can be split across assemblies.

Comment: @Richard, I do not know to whom your question was addressed. In case it was addressed to me, here is my answer. I do not mention the namespace in my question. Also, I believe that the namespace is not related to my question. Thank you.

Comment: You are confusing `File` and `Type` -- they are not the same thing; a single C# **file** can contain multiple **types**.

Comment: *"I would like to be able to check to which assembly each **file** in the project belongs"*, *"the assembly to which a **file** belongs"*, etc. You say "file" several times in your question, but you are in fact referring to types. (C# does not have a concept of a file being contained in an assembly, but it does have a concept of a type being contained in an assembly.)

Comment: @Herohtar, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are meaning with File is actualy a Type.

You can get the type this way:

```
var type = typeof(HomeController);
```

And the assembly of the type this way:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(type);
```

So alltogether:

```
var type = typeof(HomeController);
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(type);
```

More information are [provided here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: So, does that mean that each time I want to know to which assembly a file belongs I should run some code similar to the one you provided above but for my own types?

Comment: @qqqqqqq no, in .net world, each source file is "attached" to a project. Since assembly and project can be used interchangeably in the current context this means that by simple observation you can deduct which file to which assembly it belongs.

Comment: @kuskmen, does that mean that the assemblies management in most cases means the same as the projects management?

Comment: @qqqqqqq Mostly, yes

Comment: @kuskmen, imho it would be useful for others if you will post it as an answer. Thank you.